# Order by Column names with CodeIgniter and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, sql-order-by

I have a table name "events" with values

```
Id ---event_id--- Name
=====================
1-----41----------Mark
2-----41----------Kane
3-----42----------Tango
4-----43----------Louis
5-----42----------Nisa
```

How can I get values from event_id 42, then 43 and then 41. It's a tricky question because here you are telling SQL to first get me rows that match with event_id 42, then 43 and then 41.  I tried order by clause in SQL but it allows only ascending and descending.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use order by [field()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
select * from events
order by field(event_id,42,43,41)
```

Comment: Beautiful...Thanks a lot :) Btw, can I also do something like this? first get event_id 42 and then get random event_id from 43 and 41 and then the remaining one.

Comment: using field() I dont think you can get random since it will follow the order in which its specified.

Comment: that needs some case when but again if you use rand() it will be real bottleneck and you may never get an optimized query. The other way is to do UNION all `select * from table where event_id = 41` union all `select * from table where `...and for each lower one do order by rand() limit 1 and then finally select all.. but not sure how it will behave I have never tried this.

Comment: oh...thanks. we are looking at the best and optimized approach.

Comment: Can you help me out with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812509/get-peer-column-values-from-same-table-using-codeigniter-and-mysql